# How to validate if the user's account is accepted or still in pending in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I need a php file that if a user try to login, the php file will get the username and password and if it's correct it will proceed to check the status, if the account of the user is already approved or still in pending. So if the account of the user in approved it will print '1', if still in pending it will print '2' and if the username and password of the user is incorrect it will just print '3'. The problem is after the PHP file check the username and password of the user, it should check again the database if the account already approved first or still in progress before it print '1' or '2'

```
<?php

$user_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_name");
$user_pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_pass");

$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "db");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND user_pass = MD5('".$user_pass."')");

if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    $status = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT `status` FROM `user_info` WHERE `user_name`='$user_name'");
    $data2 = mysqli_fetch_object($status);
    if  ($data2 = "Approved") {
        echo '1';
    } else if ($data2 = "Pending") {
        echo '2';
    }
} else {
echo '3';
}
?>
```

Comment: What result are you getting and what are you excepting?

Comment: @gael I always get '1' even does the status of the account in the database is in "Pending". That's the only problem. I don't think it gets the value of status of the account in the database

Comment: Why do you need to do a second query? The status should already be in `$data['status']`.

Comment: It should be `if ($data2->status == "Approved")`.

Comment: Also, you're using `=` when you should be using `==` to compare.

Comment: @Barmar I actually don't know. I'm still new in coding php

Comment: md5 isn't much good these days, it's too weak to be secure and has been rainbow tabled to death. Have a read of https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do two queries. `$data` contains the row for the user, so you can just check the status there.

```
<?php

$user_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_name");
$user_pass = filter_input(INPUT_POST, "user_pass");

$mysqli = new mysqli("server", "username", "password", "db");

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE user_name='$user_name' AND user_pass = MD5('".$user_pass."')");

if ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ 
    if ($data['status'] == 'Approved') {
        echo '1';
    } else if ($data['status'] = "Pending") {
        echo '2';
    }
} else {
    echo '3';
}
?>
```